# How can I ensure that the 2nd index of my binary decision variable is equal in every solution?

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a binary decision variable `x[l][c][f]`. `F` can range between 1-6. Now I want `f` to be equal in every solution. So whenever the binary variable is equal to 1, `f` must be the same (1-6) for all non zero binary variables. So in the solution, every `x` has the same index for `f`.

```
Range F = 1..6;

Range L = 1..28;

Range C = 1..6;

dvar boolean x[L][C][F];  // bin decision variable equal to 1 if line l is jused with c carriages at a frequency of f

Forall (l in L, c in C, f in F)
(x[l][c][f]==1) => ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could

```
range F = 1..6;

range L = 1..28;

range C = 1..6;

dvar boolean x[L][C][F]; // bin decision variable equal to 1 if line l is jused with c carriages at a frequency of f

subject to
{
forall (l in L, c in C) sum(f in F) x[l][c][f]==1 ;
}
```

help ?

Or with your comment ?

```
range F = 1..6;

range L = 1..28;

range C = 1..6;


dvar boolean x[L][C][F]; // bin decision variable equal to 1 if line l is jused with c carriages at a frequency of f
dvar int nbFrequencyUsed[F];

subject to
{
forall(f in F) nbFrequencyUsed[f]==sum (l in L, c in C) x[l][c][f];
1>=sum(f in F) (nbFrequencyUsed[f]>=1);
}
```

Comment: Dear Alex,

Thank you for the fast reply but unfortunately this is not what I was looking for.
Let me try to be a bit more clear:
I want my model to be more homogeneous regarding index f. The binary variable x represent all combinations of lines, carriages, and frequencies (1008). Now, if a binary variable takes value one, f should be equal for all 1's. So f should be either 1,2,3,4,5, or 6 for all x values equal to 1. I was thinking of an if-statement.

Regards

Comment: @Dirkk: if the original question was not entirely clear, would you merge in your additional detail here into the question, by editing it? I wonder if the example data in particular would help future readers understand the question a bit more, and thus would also set the correct context for Alex's answer.